# How to cycle between two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

[image]

I'm trying to create a cycling sliding animation for set of elements, i have two arrays:

```
var elms = [elm1, elm2, elm3];
var props = [{x,y,width,height,z-index,opacite,....}, {....}, {....}];
```

on initializing, `elms` will be positioned in the same order as `props`: *"`->` is not part of the syntax it's just to make things easier to explain and it means 'do something with'"*

```
elms[0] -> props[0];
emls[1] -> props[1];
elms[2] -> props[2];
```

but then i want to cycle them like:

```
elms[0] -> props[2]
elms[1] -> props[0]
elms[2] -> props[1]
```

and then:

```
elms[0] -> props[1]
elms[1] -> props[2]
elms[2] -> props[0]
```

and so forth...

i tried this:

```
function index(n, array){
    var m = n;
    if(n > array.length){
        m = n - array.lenth;
    }else if(n < 0){
        m = array.length + n;
    }
    return m;
}

var active = 0; //the front element

function slide(direction){
    for (i=0; i< elms.length; i++)
    {
        elms[i] -> props[index(i - active, props)]
    }
    if(direction == 'fw'){
        if(active++ => elms.length){
            active = 0;
        }else{
            active++;
        }
    }else if(direction == 'bw'){
        if(active-- < 0){
            active += elms.length;
        }else{
            active--;
        }
    }
}

setInterval(function(){slide('fw')}, 3000);
```

now the above code works fine, but i'm sure this has been done many times before and i'm wondering does anyone know if there is a better less complicated way to do this which allows to loop forward and backward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using module? Have a global var that you increment each time you shift, then module that with the length of the arrays. You could access the arrays like: `props[shift%len]`

If len is 3 (as above), you could get these results if you are accessing the props in relation to the first elmsIdx (0):

POC: jsfiddle.net/Q8dBb, also this would work without modifying your arrays so I believe it would be faster

shift = 0; // (shift+elmsIdx)%len == 0;
shift = 1; // (shift+elmsIdx)%len == 1;
shift = 2; // (shift+elmsIdx)%len == 2;
shift = 3; // (shift+elmsIdx)%len == 0;
shift = 4; // (shift+elmsIdx)%len == 1;
etc

**Actually**, using an object could make it more flexible (shifting multiple ways, resetting, whatever you want to add). Here is an example for that:

```
function Shift(len) {
    var _len = len;
    var _s = 0;
    this.left = function() {
        _s = (_s + 1)% _len;
    }
    this.right = function() {
        _s = (_s - 1);
        if (_s < 0) {
            _s = _s + _len;
        }
    }
    this.get = function(idx) {
        return (_s + idx)% _len;
    }
    this.reset = function() {
        _s = 0;
    }
}
```

in use: http://jsfiddle.net/6tSup/1/

Comment: actually you'll run into problems with that (ei: if shift ends up further negative). also, the new solution I added will be more flexible... check it out.

Comment: i am using it in an object, the shift value i have in my original code resets to 0 when it reaches the array.length, so all's good :)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind modifying the props array, you can just `.shift()` off the first element and then `.push()` is onto the end of the array and then once again do:

```
elms[0] -> props[0];
emls[1] -> props[1];
elms[2] -> props[2];
```

To rotate the props array, you could just do this:

```
function rotateProps() {
    var front = props.shift();
    props.push(front);
}
```

So, each cycle just call `rotateProps()` and then repeat what you did the first time.

Comment: @razzak - use `.pop()` and `.unshift()` to rotate the other way.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks it works, but i'd rather not modify the array in this project i'm working on. i'd implement it though in my future projects. thanks again